# Object-fit: contain for a div element

Tags: html, css, object-fit

As I know, the `<img/>` have css prop: `object-fit`.

When value is `contain`: img will be display full, and there is white space (if the ratio of image is different from `<img/>`).

Now. I have a `div`, has a ratio `3/2`. The parent is an `div` with `height` and `width` is dynamic, and no ratio for parent.

How can the children always inside the parent (contain) in any ratio of parent?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }`:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

div {
  outline: solid 1px blue;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt=""></div>
<div><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt=""></div>
<div><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt=""></div>
```